# How to set struct field using base type in Go

Tags: go

If I defined a type `type myInt64 int64` how would I set it using reflection?  Code below panics reflect.Set: value of type int64 is not assignable to type main.myInt64
http://play.golang.org/p/scsXq4ofk6

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type myInt64 int64

type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
    Age  myInt64
}

func FillStruct(m map[string]interface{}, s interface{}) error {
    structValue := reflect.ValueOf(s).Elem()

    for name, value := range m {
        structFieldValue := structValue.FieldByName(name)

        val := reflect.ValueOf(value)

        structFieldValue.Set(val)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    myData := make(map[string]interface{})
    myData["Name"] = "Tony"
    myData["Age"] = int64(23)

    result := &MyStruct{}
    err := FillStruct(myData, result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: Interesting problem. Seems like something of a catch-22. Can't assign `int64` to `myInt64` but then if you try to do a conversion that fails too :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to provide the correct type for the assignment. There are no implicit type conversions.

You can either provide a `myInt64` to your function

```
myData := make(map[string]interface{})
myData["Name"] = "Tony"
myData["Age"] = myInt64(23)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/sbOdAnbz8n

Or you can convert the values during assignment

```
for name, value := range m {
    structFieldValue := structValue.FieldByName(name)
    fieldType := structFieldValue.Type()

    val := reflect.ValueOf(value)

    structFieldValue.Set(val.Convert(fieldType))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/kl0fEENY9b

Comment: Do you know why `val.Convert(fieldType)` is allowed but you can't do the conversion like `myInt64(val)` ? I assume `Convert` is something in the reflect package with a different implementation but it seems a bit silly to me that it's use is required when the other conversion *should* succeed, or at least I can't see any good reason why it's not possible to do.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal `val` is a `reflect.Value`, not an `int64`.

Comment: yeah I get that but the error ends up saying `panic: reflect.Set: value of type int64 is not assignable to type main.myInt64`. I tried to convert to `int64` and then to `myInt64` and ran into the same type if error.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal if you get that a `reflect.Value` is a different underlying type from an `int64` then I don't understand what the confusion is. You can't convert between the two, and that's why there's the `Convert` and `ConvertibleTo` methods.